# Running Web Socket Client side programming

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I just read about web sockets and written this simple client side java script. But it doesn't give me any output even if I run on Chrome browser and I don't know what is the FAULT??
May be google.com doesn't support Web sockets??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web socket Experiment</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callWebSocket() {

            var socket = new WebSocket("ws://www.google.com");

            socket.onopen = function () {
                alert("Hello, Connected To WS server");
            };

            socket.onmessage = function (e) {
                alert("The message received is : " + e.data);
            };
            socket.onerror = function (e) {
                alert("An error occured while connecting... " + e.data);
            };
            socket.onclose = function () {
                alert("hello.. The coonection has been clsoed");
            };

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Open Connecton" onclcik="callWebSocket()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Please help..

Thanks
Sneha

Comment: 1. Same-origin policies could be part of the problem. 2. No, as far as I know, Google does not use web sockets on google.com. 3. Extra `:` before `google.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you typoed `onclcik` in your input button.  Other than that, your code should work fine, except as minitech mentioned in his comment, I don't think google currently has a web socket script setup for you to use.  Try making your own server-side script to point to, or search for an existing 3rd party site example to play with (eg, quick google search and I found ws://echo.websocket.org which i tried your code on and it worked, other than the typo)

Comment: it is not a standard, it is being developed and has different levels of usability in html5 compatible browsers.

Comment: thanks a lot.. but when i executed the program...it just displayed me "connection closed" alert after few seconds in Chrome. How do i get o/p as "connection opened"?? any problem??

Comment: @CrayonViolent websocket is a standard.  See [RFC 6455](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455)

Comment: @simonc, look at the very top right of that link, it says *proposed* standard.  It is a new protocol, all the details aren't even worked out yet, but some browsers are already implementing what has been worked out, so that people can play with it and help improve and flesh it out.