# Open connection to Web socket

Tags: html, google-chrome, ubuntu, websocket

I tried to run the following html page with web sockets in google chrome (15.0.874.106 (Developer Build 107270 Linux) Ubuntu 10.04)

[Running Web Socket Client side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907927/running-web-socket-client-side-programming/10908019#comment14223890_10908019)

But i am getting the output as "Disconnected or Connection closed"

How to resolve this and open the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a current build of Chrome (we're up to 20 now).  Different versions of Chrome support [different versions of the WebSocket Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support).  You may be trying to connect to a server running a more recent version of the protocol.