# Sample web socket connection

Tags: html, websocket

I would like to know a simple sample example which sends and receives JSON message using web socket. I know how to write client side program using Web Socket. But how do I write client side program ( [Running Web Socket Client side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907927/running-web-socket-client-side-programming/10908019#comment14223890_10908019) ) using c or java web service and host it on tomcat (localhost) web server?
Here in client side i want to give my own localhost address instead of "echo... "

What are the system requirement and installations/plug-in available for these??
Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you want to do that, but maybe you should have a look at "websocketpp" if you're looking for a C++ implementation of both - client and server side.

Comment: my client is html5 and server is c or java